# Sorting sheets in Google Drive Spreadsheet using PHP API

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have a SpreadSheet on Google Drive and I'm updating the content using PHP API (https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values).

I store here reports from my projects. Each project has its sheet.

When the project has no sheet (new project), I create a new sheet for this project called by the name of a new project.

The sheets is created as a last one.

This is my current code to create a new Sheet:

```
$body = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest(
  ['requests' => ['addSheet' => ['properties' => ['title' => $project_name]]]]
);

$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $body);
```

I would like to have sheets sorted alphabetically. Excluding the first sheet, where are some global statistics.

Is there any way to change the order of the sheets using Google SpreadSheet API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution ;-)

```
$requests = [
    new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
        'updateSheetProperties' => [
            'fields' => 'index',
            'properties' => [
                'sheetId' => $sheet_id,
                'index' => $i,
            ],
        ],
    ])
];
$batchUpdateRequest = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest([
    'requests' => $requests
]);
$result = $service->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetId, $batchUpdateRequest);
```

Comment: Yes, that's it!

Answer (score 1):

### This would be the workflow:

- Each time after creating a new sheet use the method [spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) and [retrieve the sheets of the spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#Spreadsheet)
- Retrieve the `ids` and `titles` of the sheets,  pass the `ids` into an array and [sort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) the position of the `ids` as a function of `title`, as performed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439959/google-sheets-script-sort-sheets-alphabetically-within-a-spreadsheet)
- Perform an [UpdateSheetPropertiesRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatesheetpropertiesrequest), specifying the [SheetProperty](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#SheetProperties) "index" - which will move the sheet to a position corresponding to the position of the `sheetId` in the alpahabetically sorted array.